# Where did simpleminer go?

Tags: cpu-mining

With Wolfram Warptangent, where did simpleminer go?  Are there any special compilation flags that need to be set?

Answer (score 6):

simpleminer has been removed.

You can either use the miner in the daemon/wallet or any of the mining programs found on https://monerohash.com/#getting_started

Answer (score 2):

simpleminer was an obsolete program, and was removed.

It was inherited from the Cryptonote code, and it is thought to be using a Minergate protocol, though I don't think anyone's actually tried and lived to tell the tale.

If you want to pool mine, pick a miner in most pools' "Getting started" page, eg http://monero.crypto-pool.fr/#getting_started.

If you want to solo mine, run `start_mining ADDRESS THREADS` in the daemon (or just `start_mining THREADS` in the wallet), replacing ADDRESS by your Monero address, and THREADS by the number of threads to use. See [Optimal number of threads when mining](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/328/optimal-number-of-threads-when-mining/333#333) for more info on how to choose that value.